# Apache Webserver no starting, please help, Newbie

Tags: centos7

I have centos 7 , and everything was working fine untill I restarted apachectl. And it gave me following error and not starting after this.

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

Result for systemctl status httpd.service

> [root@server ~]# systemctl status httpd.service ● httpd.service - The
>   Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-05-23
>   13:02:32 CEST; 4min 5s ago
>        Docs: man:httpd(8)
>              man:apachectl(8)   Process: 24428 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 24428
>   (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> May 23 13:02:31 server.xxx.xyz systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP
>   Server... May 23 13:02:32 server.xxx.xyz httpd[24428]: (98)Address
>   already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   62.210.178.175:443 May 23 13:02:32 server.xxx.xyz httpd[24428]: no listening sockets available, shutting down May 23 13:02:32
>   server.xxx.xyz httpd[24428]: AH00015: Unable to open logs May 23
>   13:02:32 server.xxx.xyz systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process
>   exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE May 23 13:02:32 server.xxx.xyz
>   systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. May 23 13:02:32
>   server.xxx.xyz systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
>   May 23 13:02:32 server.xxx.xyz systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.

Answer (score 0):

Form the log, it seems the apache didn't restarted correctly or some other process use port 443.

You probably need to check which process use that port, if you use netstat, you might try to use this following command:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep -w ':443'
```

Comment: This command results in nothing. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the apache webserver. This for once solved the problem, but when I restart apache, it give the same error.
I think you are right that apache is not restarting correctly.